# Graphics2D.drawString() cannot use my custom font

Tags: java, swing, fonts

Here is my code:

```java
private void drawScore(Graphics2D g, int xGap, int yGap) {
        Font font = PanelUtil.getFont();
        //Font font = new Font("Fira Code", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        font.deriveFont(200f);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString("testasdasdsdasasd", 500, 50);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(status.getLocal().getScore()), GameConfig.FRAME_WIDTH / 2 - xGap, yGap);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(status.getRemote().getScore()), GameConfig.FRAME_WIDTH / 2 + xGap, yGap);
    }
```

If I use the font I have installed, it works properly; however, if I use the font inside the resource folder, only I can see is some white point. Have no idea about this.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made a low-level error: the `font.deriveFont(200f)` should be assigned and then be used. Hope my answer could help someone like me...